# Why I am getting this Compilation r error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]

Tags: c

**newbie to c programming, even though I got the output in other IDE's.  One of the IDE's showed this problem.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (a>b && a>c && a>d){
        printf("%d",a);
    }
    else if (b>a && b>c && b>d ) {
        printf("%d",b);
    }
    else if (c>a && c>b && c>d ) {
        printf("%d",c);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d",d);
    }
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    max(a,b,c,d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function `max` declared to return `int` but doesn't return anything. If you're only using it for printing, then you may as well declare it to return `void`. Alternatively (and better yet), instead of printing the result, just return it, and have the calling function (`main`) printing it instead.

Comment: E..g a compute-and-return type of function isn't generally expected to do console IO, it's expected to *compute*. Leave the reporting IO to the caller of the function whence it reaps the computation result. [Example here](https://godbolt.org/z/MMqn946z7).

Answer (score 1):

The function `int max(int a, int b, int c, int d)` is declared to return `int` but does not return anything just change the declaration to `void max(int a, int b, int c, int d)`.Or if you want to return the answer instead of printing you can just return and print in the main function.

```
int max(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (a>b && a>c && a>d){
        return a;
    }
    else if (b>a && b>c && b>d ) {
        return b;
    }
    else if (c>a && c>b && c>d ) {
        return c;
    }
    else {
        return d;
    }
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    printf("%d",max(a,b,c,d));
    return 0;
}
```